# how to find redirect source through htaccess in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site with lots of links that redirect to a small set of links.

I used the htaccess redirect 301 to redirect a user going to www.example.com/something/something_else/ , to www.example.com/my/collective/url/index.php where something and something_else are not actual folders but just keywords.
Is there a way in index.php to know which url it was redirected from?

I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it gave me nothing.

EDIT:
the rewrite rules I used are as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^something/something_else/(.*)$ /my/collective/url/$1 [R=301,L,NE,P]
```

UPDATE:
I eventually added a php script for the rewrite, in order to get the HTTP_REFERER. Seems there is no way to properly get it, since after redirect the HTTP_REFERER turns to the redirected url or disappears entirely. 
Would still be happy to get an answer though if there is a way.

Comment: You also can't trust the `HTTP_REFERER` because it is not set by all user agents!

Comment: just the referer, and it is NOT reliable. it can be forged, it might not be sent at all, blah blah blah.

Comment: This depends on the HTTP status code you are using for redirection... But you could get it by either the `REQUEST_URI` or via a RewriteRule which uses parameters.

Comment: If you could supply us with your rewriterules, we could tell you the best suitable approach for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` this will not be affected by a RewriteRule, but will not do any good no a pure redirect.

Instead of using a line like so:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

You could remove the R=301 part to not change the page location viewed by the browser, that way, the user thinks he really landed on your page using the /something/something_else link. This is also perfect for SEO... Just look out to not create too many links pointing to the same content...

Comment: I was kind of hoping to create a lot of links pointing to the same page, which will change the displayed page according to the keywords in the link. What can be so dangerous about it?

Comment: Nothing... As long as the content changes. In SEO, your site will get low ranking if multiple URLs serve the exact same content, but in your situation, this does not seem to be the case.